Is my proof correct? Suppose $A \cap B \subseteq C \setminus D$. Prove that if $x \in A$, then if $x \in D$, then $x \notin B$
I'm a high school student studying Velleman's How To Prove It without any help from a professional mathematician. I came across this problem in chapter 3 problem 9 and I am not really sure if my proof is correct since it is not similar to the solution's manual.
Suppose $A \cap B \subseteq C \setminus D$. Prove that if $x \in A$, then if $x \in D$, then $x \notin B$.
Proof: Suppose $x \in B$ and $x \in D$. Then $x$ is not in $C \setminus D$ since $x \in D$. Moreover, since $A \cap B \subseteq C \setminus D$, then $x$ is not in $A \cap B$; thereby implying that $x$ is not in $A$. So if $x \in A$, then if $x \in D$, then $x \notin B$.
Is my proof correct? I know that the statement is equivalent to $P \rightarrow (R \rightarrow Q)$, so I used the contrapositive which is equivalent to $(R \land \neg Q) \rightarrow \neg P$ to prove it. However, I'm not sure if my conclusion that $x \in A$ is valid since I know that $x \notin A \cap B$ merely implies that $x \notin B$ and $x \notin A$, not $x \in A$.

Yes, more or less Ok. Using Contraposition, you have that $x \notin A \cap B$ that contradicts the assumptions: $x \in A$ and $x \in B$.  Alternatively, form assumptions that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ you have $x \in A \cap B$ and thus $x \in C \setminus D$, contradicting the fact that $x \notin C \setminus D$.

Your proof is fine, see @Mauro ALLEGRANZA 's comment. You are making proof by contradiction.
I'll provide a neater solution for your reference: Since $A\cap B\subset C\setminus D$, you can intersect with $D$ on both sides and get $A\cap B\cap D\subset (C\setminus D)\cap D$, the right side of which is $\emptyset$ by definition of setminus. Hence you have $A\cap B\cap D=\emptyset$, coming to your conclusion now.
These proofs have basicly the same nature, but operating on sets instead of elements will sometimes make your thoughts clearer

Wow, that's actually neat!

Your proof by contradiction is fine. A direct proof is:
$$A\cap B\subseteq D^c\iff A\cap B\cap D=\varnothing\iff A\cap D\subseteq B^c.$$

Here is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.
The statement we are trying to prove can be represented as:
\begin{align*}
(\forall x\in U)((x\in A\cap B \subseteq C\backslash D) \rightarrow ((x\in A) \rightarrow ((x\in D) \rightarrow (x\not\in B))))
\end{align*}
where $U$ is the universe of discourse. Consequently, its denial can be expresses as:
\begin{align*}
(\exists x\in U)((x\in A\cap B\subseteq C\backslash D)\wedge(x\in A)\wedge(x\in D)\wedge(x\in B))
\end{align*}
Based on such considerations, we shall prove the proposed claim by absurd.
If $x\in A\cap B\cap D\subseteq A\cap B\subseteq C\backslash D$, this implies that $x\in D$ and $x\in C\backslash D = C\cap D^{c}$.
In other words, one concludes that $x\in D\cap (C\cap D^{c}) = C\cap(D\cap D^{c}) =\varnothing$, which is a contradiction.
Hopefully this helps!
